# How can i return List & Integer from C# to Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to return `List<ClassName>` & count(int) from code-behind(C#) to javascript. How can i do this?

Comment: List of any class e.g EmpDetails

Comment: More information about your specific situation would be helpful, but as general advice you could do an AJAX POST to a web service that returns yor data in JSON form.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some code. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JavaScriptSerializer:

```
var myClass = new ClassName();

... 

var jSon = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var OutPut = jSon.Serialize(myClass);

Response.Write(OutPut);
```

You have to import this namespace: `System.Web.Script.Serialization`

**UPDATE:**

You can use jQuery to post the request:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'WebForm2.aspx',
            data: {},
            dataType: 'json',
            complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
                var Response = $.parseJSON(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                alert(Response.Classes[0].Name);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and this is the code-behind:

```
public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var classWrapper = new ClassWrapper();

        classWrapper.Classes.Add(new ClassName() { Name = "Test 1" });
        classWrapper.Classes.Add(new ClassName() { Name = "Test 2" });
        classWrapper.Classes.Add(new ClassName() { Name = "Test 3" });
        classWrapper.Count = classWrapper.Classes.Count;


        var jSon = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var OutPut = jSon.Serialize(classWrapper);

        Response.Write(OutPut);
    }
}

public class ClassWrapper
{
    public ClassWrapper()
    {
        Classes = new List<ClassName>();
    }
    public List<ClassName> Classes { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

public class ClassName
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Few tricks for **ASP.NET** (in MVC would be easier).

in the HTML of WebForm2.aspx remove all the HTML but leave page directive:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="AutocompleteASPNET.WebForm2" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to achieved the required functionality is to use Ajax.

For this create a page method in code behind and call that method in client side through javascript.

For more details how to call server side method from jquery,checkout the following link

[Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)